# QGSdk SetToken shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x50) error

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have the below code in

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method
    QGSdk *qgsdk=[[QGSdk alloc]init];
    [qgsdk setToken:deviceToken];
```

It is showing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and I could not solve the issue. Can any one guide.

**Note:** It was working fine previously but now it is showing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I Have enable

**NSDebugEnabled, NSZombieEnabled, NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled**

but still I could not solve the issue. Please guide.

Comment: Please check QGSdk is supported a string format or NSData Format.
and pass the respective parameter at the line 
[qgsdk setToken:deviceToken]; // Please check "deviceToken" which format you have to send.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your QGSdk is supported NSData format.
And you are sending a NSString in method as parameter.

```
QGSdk *qgsdk=[[QGSdk alloc]init];
[qgsdk setToken:deviceToken]; // Please convert your NSString into NSData and then check
```

Comment: No Parvendra... I am sending NSData only.